# Reduce time complexity of evaluation of testset when using transform with CalculateFeatureContribution in training for explainability in ML.NET

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I needed to reduce time complexity of the transform due to performance issues as CalculateFeatureContribution provided by ML.NET 1.7.0(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.explainabilitycatalog.calculatefeaturecontribution?view=ml-dotnet) is increasing the time taken multifolds

```
        var testSet = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<ModelInput>(evalset);

        IDataView predictions;
        using (var v = new startwatch("Evaluate"))
        {
            predictions = model1.Transform(testSet); //evaluates each testcase and computes an array of feature contribution.

        }
```

This generic function is used to evaluate the testcases.

Time complexity when CalculateFeatureContribution is included in training pipeline is 4.486 ms per test item.

Time complexity when CalculateFeatureContribution is **NOT** included in training pipeline is 0.756 ms per test item.

The excess time taken is to compute weight of each feature for each item, but is there a possible way to reduce the time taken when CalculateFeatureContribution is included.